# Output of perl Digest::MD5 md5($data) and java MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest($data) are different

Tags: java, perl, security, encryption

I have a perl script which uses Digest::MD5 md5($data) to obtain the 16 byte digest(which is in non readable form - binary) and this digest is used to encrypt the data.
Now i have to reverse the above procedure in java i.e first i need to obtain 16 byte digest using MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest($data) and decrypt the message.

> Now i am not sure that output digest of perl Digest::MD5 md5($data) and java digest MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest($data) are same or not how do i validate this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

1) Convert the Perl md5 from [byte to hex](http://blog-en.openalfa.com/how-to-work-with-binary-data-in-a-perl-script)

2) Convert the Java md5 from byte to hex ([examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java))

3) Compare the outputs

This is the Java code for the MD5 and convertion in Hex:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;


public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    System.out.println("Start");

    String res=MD5("35799510369");

    System.out.print("res:"+res);

  }

 public static String MD5( String source ) {
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance( "MD5" );
            byte[] bytes = md.digest( source.getBytes("UTF-8") );
            return getString( bytes );
        } catch( Exception e )  {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }//end MD5()

    private static String getString( byte[] bytes ) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for( int i=0; i<bytes.length; i++ )
        {
            byte b = bytes[ i ];
            String hex = Integer.toHexString((int) 0x00FF & b);
            if (hex.length() == 1)
            {
                sb.append("0");
            }
            sb.append( hex );
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }// end getString()
```

Copy and Paste the previus code in [this online compiler](http://www.compilejava.net/) and press COMPILE AND EXECUTE; next compare this output with the [Perl md5 online script](https://code.hackerearth.com/c4681er?key=ab626d9b100a40b5040001360a1dcb50) output.

---

For input=35799510369

- Perl output:

Md5 digest is .S<ë_»X³ëE&â®

The hexadecimal representation of the digest is: 012e533c9aeb5f96bb58b3eb4526e2ae

- Java output:

res:012e533c9aeb5f96bb58b3eb4526e2ae

Good luck

Comment: But the problem is i don't have access to modify perl script.

Comment: For testing the Perl md5 try this online [script](https://code.hackerearth.com/c4681er?key=ab626d9b100a40b5040001360a1dcb50): put your input in $data and press 'Compile and Run' button

Comment: Hi Marco, do u know any java equivalent api for perl method Digest::MD5 md5($data)  i.e which returns binary output and how do i compare the output of perl md5 and java md5 output?

Comment: If this answer helps you don't forget accept it as correct